# Creating procedure inside IF section

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need some help with simple SQL code:

```
DECLARE @procExists int
SET @procExists = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES WHERE ROUTINE_SCHEMA = 'dbo' AND ROUTINE_NAME = 'Table_Exists' AND ROUTINE_TYPE = 'PROCEDURE')
IF NOT @procExists > 0 
BEGIN
    -- test query
    -- SELECT 'Something' = @procExists;

    -- error throwing code
    -- CREATE PROCEDURE Table_Exists
    --     @schemaName varchar(50),
    --     @tableName varchar(50)
    -- AS
    --     RETURN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = @schemaName AND TABLE_NAME = @tableName)
END
```

The simple code above:
- declares an int variable
- checks if procedure dbo.Table_Exists exists
- IF NOT exists it creates it

My problem is this error information:

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 9
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'PROCEDURE'.
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 13
Must declare the scalar variable "@schemaName".
```

I don't know why, but..
- when i execute 'CREATE PROCEDURE' body **alone** it works
- when i execute whole IF section **excluding** 'CREATE PROCEDURE' body, simple query works
- when i execute whole IF section **including** 'CREATE PROCEDURE' body, error is thrown

What am i missing?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

CREATE PROCEDURE has to be in it's own batch

So, dynamic SQL is one way:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('Table_Exists') IS NULL
BEGIN
    EXEC ('CREATE PROCEDURE Table_Exists
         @schemaName varchar(50),
         @tableName varchar(50)
     AS
         RETURN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = @schemaName AND TABLE_NAME = @tableName)
')
END
```

or DROP first

```
IF OBJECT_ID('Table_Exists') IS NOT NULL
  DROP PROC Table_Exists
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE Table_Exists
         @schemaName varchar(50),
         @tableName varchar(50)
     AS
         RETURN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = @schemaName AND TABLE_NAME = @tableName)
GO
```

Note the use of OBJECT_ID to see if the proc exists.

Comment: Hmm.. Should i prefer checking with OBJECT_ID or through INFORMATION_SCHEMA? I've read somewhere that using INFORMATION_SCHEMA is better idea.

Comment: @dygi: I always use OBJECT_ID but it's up to you. In other RDBMS you'd use `CREATE OR REPLACE`, or `CREATE IF NOT EXISTS` anyway so don't worry about "portability"

Comment: One thing more. Is this modification correct and safe:  OBJECT_ID(db_name()+N'.dbo.Table_Exists', N'P')

Comment: @dygi: yes, but you can't have `CREATE PROC db_name()+ '.dbo.Table_Exists ` so you have to be in the correct DB context already. And you can't have USE in dynamic SQL with a CREATE PROC...

Answer (score 20):

You can do this using `SET NOEXEC ON`. This instructs SQL Server to ignore all SQL code until `SET NOEXEC OFF` is reached.

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT *
          FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES
          WHERE ROUTINE_TYPE = 'PROCEDURE'
          AND ROUTINE_SCHEMA = 'dbo'
          AND ROUTINE_NAME = 'HelloWorld')
BEGIN
    SET NOEXEC ON
END
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.HelloWorld
AS
    PRINT 'Hello world'
GO

SET NOEXEC OFF
GO
```

Comment: This is clean. I love it.

Answer (score 4):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187926.aspx):

> The CREATE PROCEDURE statement cannot be combined with other Transact-SQL statements in a single batch.

Therefore, what you are trying to do is not possible, unless you are fine with implementing it via a dynamic query.

Answer (score 0):

```
if OBJECT_ID('PROC1') IS NULL  
   EXEC('CREATE PROCEDURE DBO.PROC1 AS SELECT 1')

GO

ALTER PROCEDURE DBO.PROC1(@PARAM1 INT, @PARAM2 INT)

AS
```

.................